# How do we hide the first zero in axes matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot histogram.

```
plt.bar([1,2,3], [4,5,6],color="r",align="center")
```

I don't wanna plot the zero in the beginning of the axes. This ridiculous way to do it.

```
plt.yticks(range(len([1,2,3])),["None"]+[1,2,3])
```

Is there any good way to do that ?

Comment: why did you point to Google translate ?

Answer (score 7):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576805/matplotlib-hiding-specific-ticks-on-x-axis). There isn't a much less ridiculous way to do what you're trying to do. This snippet, adapted from the linked question,

```
ax = plt.gca()
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks() 
xticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This solution does not work for the latest version of matplotlib.
Use the following code to hide the origin (0) for the y-axis:

```
axes.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1].label1.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: this one worked for me, i just needed to change [1] to [0]. Thanks!