# Removing specific xaxis tick labels in a log-plot, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a log-log contour plot for which I needed to display the minor ticks. So I used

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(fmt("%.1f"))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(fmt("%.1f"))
```

where `fmt` is `from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter as fmt`

This works fine and gives me all the minor ticks. However as you can see from the attached image, the x-axis ticks, **especially `7.0,8.0 and 9.0` are the ticks that overlap**, and I want to **specifically remove only them, but have the other minor ticks as they are.**

Is this possible? I am not able to find a code that removes specific minor ticks.

[image]

Comment: @:Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576805/matplotlib-hiding-specific-ticks-on-x-axis

Comment: @George I actually found a much easier solution [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567724/matplotlib-so-log-axis-only-has-minor-tick-mark-labels-at-specified-points-also) immediately after I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after posting the question, I found an easy solution.

It is to use `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.FixedLocator([2,3,4,5]))`

The list inside the `FixedLocator` does the job.